# How to unlink notes from each other?

Tags: ableton-live

I'm using Ableton Live 11.

I've used the piano roll to create a bass line, but even though notes are (seemingly) unlinked from each other, the sound is played continuously and only its pitch changes in time (as if you played a guitar string and then just moved your hand on the fret board without playing subsequent notes).

What I'd like to achieve is that every note was played independently (as if I'd play a string every time). How can I do that?

[image: Notes]

Comment: Hi Spook. I don't use that DAW, but could it just be the instrument's voice mode is set to legato or single trigger or something? What instrument are you using? A lot of bass synths and emulators play in single trigger monophonic mode, so the envelope only triggers once with closely-spaced notes like this.